# angularJs Jasmine UnitTesting the component section

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Here is my part of component file

===================================

```
angular.module(window.__env.appName)
        .component(__Name, {
        templateUrl: __Path + "/view/" +window.__env.platform +'.html',
        controller: Controller,
        controllerAs: 'vm'
});
```

I would like to test it, how?

an simple example will be appreciated?

Comment: What do you want to test? That it comes up with the correct templateURL? That the controller works? That the controller is instantiated correctly as vm?

Comment: I would like to write some Unit Test to test if it contain the <h2> tag or not, and if so check if it match teh sam class name

Comment: There are multiple examples in the official AngularJS tutorial that show how to look for things in the element that gets built. Here is a link to one https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_10